# Windows SmartScreen and WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, installation

I created installer for my WPF's application in formula file msi and when I install program on another computer I get message from Windows SmartScreen that program is dangerous.

What should I do if I don't want to get this message?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Sign your code using Signtool.exe and a valid code certificate from a Certificate Authority (like VeriSign or Thawte).

The certificates cost money and need to be renewed after a certain amount of time - generally this also means that you will need to be checked out by the certificate supplier as otherwise you could sign malicious code which they have said is "safe".

[Thawte.com - Code Signing](https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/)